# How do I prevent PHP CS Fixer from fixing specific function names?

Tags: php, annotations, phpcs, php-cs-fixer

When using PHP CS Fixer to resolve syntax errors on file save and using the **Symfony** rule set, any function names that are not **camelCase** will be corrected (as expected).

However when writing PHP Unit based tests, it's often common practice to make the function names **snake_case**. This normally means that PHP CS Fixer will resolve the issue automatically, even when not required.

Is there a specific annotation that can be placed above a function to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP CS Fixer does not have a rule to change all function names from `snake_case` to `camelCase`.

However, there is a rule [`php_unit_method_casing`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/v2.18.4/doc/rules/php_unit/php_unit_method_casing.rst) which enforces camel (or snake) case for PHPUnit test methods, and in [Symfony](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/v2.18.4/doc/ruleSets/Symfony.rst) rule set it's used with default value, which is camel case.

This is what you want to change, by overriding the rule from **Symfony** rule set with non-default version:

```php
[
    'php_unit_method_casing' => ['case' => 'snake_case'],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3846), it is a design decision to not allow for exceptions per block of code.

If your unit tests are in a separate directory or even separate files, you may use `exclude` and `notPath` accordingly as described in the [project's docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/2.18/doc/config.rst).